# Labeling and using links that have alternate Spanish translation

Tags: usability, navigation, user-expectation, accessibility, terminology

I need to convey to the user that a link presented in English to a site or doc is also offered in Spanish. What's the best way to show this? Visualization through parenthetical (Espagnol), a flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are these links being displayed? 
If it's inline with text *(Espanol)* would make the most sense.
If it's in a list of multiple links a flag could be a clear visual indicator but it might then be appropriate to display flags on all links. In Canada it's not uncommon just to see (EN) or (FR) beside links.